# Surjective marriages

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Let $M, W\neq \emptyset$ be sets and $K\subseteq M\times W$. We say that $(M, W, K)$ has a *marriage* if there is an injective function $f:M\to W$ such that $f\subseteq K$.

If $(M,W, K)$ has a marriage, is there $W'\subseteq W$ such that

1. $(M, W', K\cap(M\times W'))$ has a marriage, and
2. every marriage $f: M\to W'$ is surjective

?

Comment: Why $W'=f(M)$ does not work?

Comment: Yes iff $M$ is finite.

Comment: If not, for complete bipartite graph on countable sets the answer is negative, right?

Comment: Yes, there's no right to expect matchings from $M$ to $W$ to be bijective once the graph is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may be yes under certain finiteness conditions, for example, K being a disjoint union of finite marriages.  However, for the complete countable bipartite graph, any restriction of M and W to countably infinite subsets induces a complete graph on those subsets, and it is easy to find marriages on this subgraph that are not surjective. So in general the answer is no.

Gerhard "Characterization Seems To Be Harder" Paseman, 2017.11.09.